# how to clone the main document dom in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I try to clone my document node but it's not working.

I try this code

```
const dom = document.clone(true);
```

I have this error

```
TypeError: document.clone is not a function
```

I thinkg it's very simple but i don't find yet.

Thanks for help

Comment: The [docs for Node methods of the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#methods) are on MDN. Googling “mdn document.clone” finds the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) as the first result. Googling “site:stackoverflow.com js clone document” finds [a relevant Q&A page](/q/45946695/4642212) as the first result, suggesting `document.cloneNode(true)`. Executing `document.clone` in the console yields `undefined`. Typing `document.clone` suggests `.cloneNode`. I’m not sure why you gave up right after seeing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
const dom = document.cloneNode(true);

console.log(dom);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery

```
$('document').clone()
```

without jquery

```
document.cloneNode(true)
```